# Uniform Continuity of a Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I'm preparing for a real analysis course this summer and came across the following problem in Carothers, but I'm unsure how to approach it:

Fix $y\in l_{\infty}$ and define $g:l_{1} \to l_{1}$ by $g(x)=(x_{n}y_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Show that $g$ is uniformly continuous.

I know that uniform continuity is defined such that a single $\delta$ works uniformly for all points $x$ and $y$: Given metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$, a function $f: X \to Y$ is uniformly continuous if for every real number $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all $x,y \in X, d|x-y|<\delta$ implies $\rho|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$. However, I'm not sure how to apply this definition in $l_{\infty}$ and $l_{1}$ spaces.

Comment: See answer. From reading your question I think you may want to review what the sequence spaces are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to notice that the sequence spaces are normed spaces and that every norm induces a metric. Namely, given $ (X,|| \cdot ||)$ a normed space then $||x - y||$, induces the metric. This is a very easy fact to check by properties of norms. Now, to the question at hand.

Let $x,z \in \ell^1$ such that $||x-z|| < \delta$, where this norm is in $\ell^1$. Given y an $\ell^{\infty}$ we have that

$||g(x)-g(z)|| \leq ||y||_{\ell^{\infty}} ||x-z||$. 
(At this stage you really just need to write out what the norm is).

So select $\delta =\epsilon / ||y||_{\ell^{\infty}}$. Hence, we have that g is uniformly continuous.